# Can this code be used with an array of custom objects?

Tags: objective-c, arrays, cocoa-touch, nskeyedarchiver, nscoding

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:myArray forKey:@"myArray"];
```

If I make an array of custom objects conform to the NSCoding protocol, then does the above work? Do I have to make both the custom class and the view controller that holds the array of custom objects conform to the NSCoding protocol or just the custom class? Do I have to use NSKeyedArchiver somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you will need to archive your array, either with `NSKeyedArchiver` or `NSArchiver`. If you first archive the array into a NSData object:

```
NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:myArray];
```

You can then store that data in NSUserDefaults like so:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:data forKey:@"myArray"];
```

To load the array, use:

```
NSData *data = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"myArray"];
NSArray *myArray = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
```

If you want to use an NSMutableArray then just replace any `NSArray` occurrences in the code above with `NSMutableArray`. ***OR*** you can just `NSMutableArray *myMutableArray = [myArray mutableCopy]` will give you a NSMutableArray to work with.

But then hey, if you are going to the trouble of making it NSCoding compliant, why not just archive it to a file?

The documentation that made me think that you will need to use an archiver is [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/StoringNSColorInDefaults.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001693-BAJBFGED) so that you can check for yourself.

Comment: What if I want to use an NSMutableArray?

Comment: Note that the objects in the array must conform to the `NSCoding` protocol if they must be archived.